# Using a UITableView subclass with a UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How can I tell my `UITableViewController` to use my custom `UITableView` subclass for it's `tableView` instead of a regular `UITableView`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set the UITableViewController.tableView property to an instance of your custom UITableView subclass.

Comment: let's say I do this in `initWithStyle:` after I set `self = [super initWithStyle:style]`. How do I know what changes `-[UITableViewController initWithStyle:]` made to its `tableView`? I might be undoing those. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512793/objective-c-how-to-change-the-class-of-an-object-at-runtime

Comment: Imho, the nicest place for this is to override `loadView` with something like `self.tableView = [[MyTableViewSubclass alloc] init]` or something of the sort.

Comment: If you do that, make sure to set the `delegate` and `dataSource` too or your table won't load anything.

Answer (score 7):

In interface builder associate the tableview class with your custom tableview in the identity inspector view

Answer (score -3):

A UITableViewController is just a UIViewController with a UITableView instance and the viewController set as the delegate and dataSource for the table. The viewController implements stubs for those delegate methods.

You can do it yourself by having a UIViewController implement the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols. Then in the UIViewController's loadView (or viewDidLoad) method set the tableView instance's dataSource and delegate to self.

You can use your own table subclass there.

Comment: This is misleading. UITableViewController also includes keyboard avoidance, for example.

Comment: what is keyboard avoidance ?

Comment: when you have a text field inside a cell the table is resized when the keyboard comes up and the text field is kept in view.

Comment: Not true, uitableviewcontroller doesnt have a view property. There are more differences