# Google Analytics: Several Questions about deployment

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I have several questions about deployment GA.

1. Where I should add `[tracker sendView:@"View Name"]`? (My assumption: `-(void)loadView`)
2. How I can log sessions? (Only by sending custom events?)
3. Should I use everywhere inheritence from `GAIViewController`? (this is not good enough and seems very ugly)
4. If I use `[tracker sendView:@"View Name"]`, what happens? (Did I need to RE-sendView?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I suggest adding `[tracker sendView:@"View Name"]` into `-viewWillAppear`. You will receive event when the app is about to show to user the view, not only the time is was loaded.
2. Sessions are logged by GAI automatically. Two hits are said to belong to one session, if they are received in less than 30 min by default. Also, as you've mentioned, you can manually create sessions.
3. Yes, either you inherit from `GAIViewController`, or you place `-sendView` into every controller class's code. One another way is to use [Posing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211616/hidden-features-of-objective-c) (see second answer), and make `GAIViewController` pose as `UIViewController`. I'm not quite sure, if it works, but seems to fit your problem.
4. What do you mean by "Did I need to RE-sendView?"? Every time you want GAI to log the fact, that user has moved into some view, you call `-sendView`. Tracker will send that info to Google, and you will get information like average number of transitions into that view by session, or number of users, currently watching this view.

Also, I  find Flurry much more user-friendly, than GAI. Do think of creating your own Tracker class, which will send both GAI and Flury info.