# How to change the diagrams displayed in the same view?

Tags: ios, xcode

How to change the diagrams displayed in the same view?

I have a view inside a view controller.
This view has another view inside it, to which I have allocated a custom class (sub-classing UIView). 
This custom class has the code to draw interactive diagrams in this view.
The interactive code is operated by sliders in the main view.
I have all this in interface builder.

What if I want to draw a completely different diagram in this view?
I would like to be able to allocate a new class to this view, with a different set of drawing code? But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but [changing the class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211616/hidden-features-of-objective-c/679866#679866) is [not advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512793/objective-c-how-to-change-the-class-of-an-object-at-runtime)

Here are a few suggestions:

1 / Replace customView1 with a different view instance of the right type in the same location as your first view...

```
   self.customView2 = [[CustomView2 alloc] initWithFrame:self.customView1.frame];
   [self.view addSubView:self.customView2];
   [self.customView1 removeFromSuperView];
```

This example uses a distinct property for each of the swapped subviews, but you could use a single property just to refer to the current subview - this could help link up your sliders to do the right thing to the diagrams. If you are doing a lot of this you will need to think about memory issues - when customView1 has gone, will you be reusing it? You can keep it hanging around in a (strong) property (faster, needs more memory), or create a new one each time (slower, needs less memory).

2 / if you want to toggle between them, you could place both in Interface Builder and toggle their `hidden` properties or their order in the view hierarchy (`self.view.subviews` array). Saves having to constantly recreate the views.

3 (better...) / Keep to a single subclass of UIView and use properties to affect the diagram that gets drawn...

```
 //CustomView.h

 @property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL drawDiagram1;
 @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL drawDiagram2;

 //CustomView.m

 - (void)drawRect {
    if (drawDiagram1) [self drawDiagram1];
    if (drawDiagram2) [self drawDiagram2];
 }

- (void) drawDiagram1 { 
     //drawDiagram1 code here
}

- (void) drawDiagram2 {
     //drawDiagram2 code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I like option 3.